# Laravel project transfer to another server displayed 404 error

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, php-7.4

In the old server, the project is working fine. I had given it to its backup folder. The database is already transferred to a new server. Now I transferred the whole project folder. For better understanding, Let's assume that the old project URL is **[www.oldproject.com](http://www.oldproject.com)**. Now I transferred it like this : **[www.newdomain.com/newproject](http://www.newdomain.com/newproject)** I put the whole laravel project in **newproject** folder. Now its **displayed 404 error**.

I am new to laravel. My **laravel version is 7.30.1** and my server **PHP version is 7.4.26**

I am new to laravel and I don't know how to solve this. I changed

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'newdomain.com/newproject'], function()
```

in newdomain.com/newproject/routes/web.php

Please guide me how to make run this project. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

shame it took this long for an answer. but I would have said in your apache2 sites-available, create and enable one with alias included, like

Alias /newproject "/var/www/html/newproject/public"